# how browser handle repaint when i change the dom's color?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
    })
})
```

As i think, the background-color of body would first transform to red, and then transform to blue. But the result is that the background-color of body is transform to blue, the red is ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Although javascript timers are inaccurate
they take time to run from creation
but both timers you don't give a specific time
which is equivalent to setTimeout((...), 0)
Even if the javascript event loop mechanism were to execute
will result in a difference in the order of execution of the two
but the execution is still very fast
He can't be so slow that you can't notice the two color changes at 0 time difference
So whether it's for js or v8
This is a very bad performance
So if you want to achieve the desired effect
you can add a time to the timer inside

```js
 setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
    }, 10)
})
```